# WordPress WPGlobus: how to generate localized URLs in template files?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multilingual

I'm using the WPGlobus plugin in my multi-language WordPress website. In one of my template files, I have hard coded a link to a page.

```
example.com/page
```

It works for the default language. But I need to change that URL according to the selected language. For example:

```
example.com/jp/page
```

Is there a helper function to generate localized URL dynamically?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct way to do it. Hope it would help someone else too.

```
WPGlobus_Utils::localize_url(site_url('page'))
```

You can use **WPGlobus_Utils::localize_url** function.